# Android BroadCast Receiver runs in UI thread

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

My scenario is to fetch data from server and display it.

I am running a different process for fetching data from server but my app is hanging during download.

I use a broadcast receiver to send response from other process to UI thread.

I think BroadCastReceiver runs in UI thread? Am I doing anything wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the BroadcastReceivers method `onReceive` is running on the main thread, you can specify that it runs on a separate thread if you want, there is a method for that. The method is `registerReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler)`

Check the docs of the [onReceive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) method for more info